# looping through files Iteratively

Tags: c#, recursion, iteration

```
static void PrintDirectories(string path, int level = 0)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < level; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]);
            PrintDirectories(dirs[i], level + 1);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to write this recursive code with iterative approach without using stack and list, I'm out of ideas and internet hasn't given me a direct answer yet.

Comment: You mean something like using the [overloaded version of `Directory.GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to specify to search through subdirectories?

Comment: @UnholySheep no, I mean using normal version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple anser is **no**.

You are dealing with a recursive data structure (directory tree). So, you either do the recursion, which is the easiest way, or use stack to keep the current list of directories.

of course you can flatten it first, using this approach, creating a flat list of everything. Than you can print the list in a simple loop.